# How to modify this nested case classes with "Seq" fields?

Tags: scala, case-class, lenses

Some nested case classes and the field `addresses` is a `Seq[Address]`:

```
// ... means other fields
case class Street(name: String, ...)
case class Address(street: Street, ...)
case class Company(addresses: Seq[Address], ...)
case class Employee(company: Company, ...)
```

I have an employee:

```
val employee = Employee(Company(Seq(
    Address(Street("aaa street")),
    Address(Street("bbb street")),
    Address(Street("bpp street")))))
```

It has 3 addresses.

And I want to capitalize the streets start with "b" only. My code is mess like following:

```
val modified = employee.copy(company = employee.company.copy(addresses = 
    employee.company.addresses.map { address =>
        address.copy(street = address.street.copy(name = {
          if (address.street.name.startsWith("b")) {
            address.street.name.capitalize
          } else {
            address.street.name
          }
        }))
      }))
```

The `modified` employee is then:

```
Employee(Company(List(
    Address(Street(aaa street)), 
    Address(Street(Bbb street)), 
    Address(Street(Bpp street)))))
```

I'm looking for a way to improve it, and can't find one. Even tried [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle), but can't apply it to this problem.

Is there any way to make it better?

---

PS: there are two key requirements:

1. use only immutable data
2. don't lose other existing fields

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Peter Neyens points out, Shapeless's SYB works really nicely here, but it will modify *all* `Street` values in the tree, which may not always be what you want. If you need more control over the path, Monocle can help:

```
import monocle.Traversal
import monocle.function.all._, monocle.macros._, monocle.std.list._

val employeeStreetNameLens: Traversal[Employee, String] =
  GenLens[Employee](_.company).composeTraversal(
    GenLens[Company](_.addresses)
      .composeTraversal(each)
      .composeLens(GenLens[Address](_.street))
      .composeLens(GenLens[Street](_.name))
  )

  val capitalizer = employeeStreeNameLens.modify {
    case s if s.startsWith("b") => s.capitalize
    case s => s
  }
```

As Julien Truffaut points out in an edit, you can make this even more concise (but less general) by creating a lens all the way to the first character of the street name:

```
import monocle.std.string._

val employeeStreetNameFirstLens: Traversal[Employee, Char] =
  GenLens[Employee](_.company.addresses)
    .composeTraversal(each)
    .composeLens(GenLens[Address](_.street.name))
    .composeOptional(headOption)

val capitalizer = employeeStreetNameFirstLens.modify {
  case 'b' => 'B'
  case s   => s
}
```

There are symbolic operators that would make the definitions above a little more concise, but I prefer the non-symbolic versions.

And then (with the result reformatted for clarity):

```
scala> capitalizer(employee)
res3: Employee = Employee(
  Company(
    List(
      Address(Street(aaa street)),
      Address(Street(Bbb street)),
      Address(Street(Bpp street))
    )
  )
)
```

Note that as in the Shapeless answer, you'll need to change your `Employee` definition to use `List` instead of `Seq`, or if you don't want to change your model, you could build that transformation into the `Lens` with an `Iso[Seq[A], List[A]]`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are open to replacing the `addresses` in `Company` from `Seq` to `List`, you can use "Scrap Your Boilerplate" from shapeless ([example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sybclass.scala)).

```
import shapeless._, poly._

case class Street(name: String)
case class Address(street: Street)
case class Company(addresses: List[Address])
case class Employee(company: Company)

val employee = Employee(Company(List(
    Address(Street("aaa street")),
    Address(Street("bbb street")),
    Address(Street("bpp street")))))
```

You can create a polymorphic function which capitalizes the name of a `Street` if the name starts with a "b".

```
object capitalizeStreet extends ->(
  (s: Street) => {
    val name = if (s.name.startsWith("b")) s.name.capitalize else s.name
    Street(name)
  }
)
```

Which you can use as :

```
val afterCapitalize = everywhere(capitalizeStreet)(employee)
// Employee(Company(List(
//   Address(Street(aaa street)), 
//   Address(Street(Bbb street)), 
//   Address(Street(Bpp street)))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That's really cool. I finally got a chance to know how powerful shapeless is!

Comment: Nice answer, but see mine for a warning (this will transform _any_ street names in the data structure).

Answer (score 2):

> Take a look at [quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens)

You could do it like this

```
import com.softwaremill.quicklens._

case class Street(name: String)
case class Address(street: Street)
case class Company(address: Seq[Address])
case class Employee(company: Company)
object Foo {
  def foo(e: Employee) = {
    modify(e)(_.company.address.each.street.name).using {
      case name if name.startsWith("b") => name.capitalize
      case name => name
    }
  }
}
```